# 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': while iterating over value retrieved from dictionary using django template

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a context dictionary entry `objectives` that maps objective query objects to a list of tests that belong to that objective.  Example code:

```
objectives = Objective.objects.filter(requirement=requirement)
context_dict["requirements"][requirement] = objectives
for objective in objectives:
    tests = Test.objects.filter(objective=objective)   
    context_dict["objectives"][objective] = tests
```

In my django html template, I iterate over objectives and display them.  I then want to iterate over the tests that belong to these objectives.  When I do this:

```
{% for test in {{ objectives|get_item:objective }} %}
```

I get a `TemplateSyntaxError: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y':`

In the application/templatetags directory, I have:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
...
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

If instead I make `{{ objectives|get_item:objective }}` a JS variable, I see that it does indeed produce a list, which I should be able to iterate over.  Of course, I can't mix JS variables and the django template tags, so this is only for debugging:

```
var tests = {{ objectives|get_item:objective }}

var tests = [<Test: AT399_8_1>, <Test: AT399_8_2>, <Test: AT399_8_3>, <Test: AT399_8_4>, <Test: AT399_8_5> '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

How do I iterate over this list in the django template tag?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot have `{{...}}` syntax inside `{% ... %}` tags. Replace `{{ objectives|get_item:objective }}` with the equivalent python code.

Comment: @Bakuriu You can't do a dictionary access inside `{%...%}` tags though - the equivalent python code would be `objectives[objective]`, which won't work.

Comment: @JeremyWeirich dictionary access in django templates use the `.` operator. `{{ dictionary.key }}` prints the value but it wouldn't work for you as the key cannot be a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot user `{{...}}` inside the `{%...%}`

What you can try is changing your filter to an assignment tag and using that value in the loop

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

And then in your template use it as

```
{% get_item objectives objective as tests %}
{% for test in test %}  
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of all this if your models are proper with foreign keys I would do something like

```
{% for objective in requirement.objective_set.all %}  
    {% for test in objective.test_set.all %}  
        ....
    {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

In my context I would pass only the `requirement`

Comment: This works.  Reading up on it more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags).

Comment: Regarding your edit: `objective_set.all` returns nothing, but I think that's because I have the foreignkeys relate up to the parents, instead of down to the children.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: If your model has a field `requirement = model.ForeignKey(Requirement)` it creates a reverse relation with the modelname_set or anything that you set as `related_name`. You can then use reverse relationships for lookups.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/ for more reading

Comment: Excellent, I have the related_name parameter set, but it had the same name as the model class.  Changing it to a more logical name made it work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

You already have an answer, but note that dropping the `{{ }}` tags and keeping everything else the same would have worked fine.

```
{% for test in objectives|get_item:objective %}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **This is Right Answer for  Using Django if else and for loop **

***Note :- We Have to Put  Key in  " " string (Double quotes) some time produce an error so That is good way bcz i faced that problem whwn i Learned***

```
{% if    'numbers'|length > 0  %}
            {% for i in numbers %}
                 {% if i > 20 %}
                     {{i}}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
             
 {% else %}
    Empty
 {% endif %}
```